# pelican blog define metadata for category index page

Tags: python, metadata, categories, pelican

I want to organize a blog into multiple categories. For each category index page I want to add some metadata like title, description, meta etc. specific to the category.

Pelican uses folders to split posts into categories but how do I define the metadata for each category? Is it possible to use a metadata file to put into each category folder?

Answer (score 2):

You might try adding a key/value dictionary to your Pelican settings file that contains your category metadata, and then access that information from within your theme's `index.html` template.

Comment: that sounds doable but I still have in mind that the blog author can write the content himself. maintaining dictionaries in a settings file looks more like programming to me

Comment: To answer your original question, no: Pelican does not currently have a built-in way to add meta-data to a category. The answer I provided above should work, and I don't think `KEY = "value"` is programming. That said, one could write a Pelican plugin to provide more direct support for category meta-data. Hop onto the #pelican IRC channel (Freenode) and ask Avaris about this; I believe he said he might be willing to help implement a `taxonomy-metadata` plugin.

Comment: To further expand on Justin's comment, your pelican configuration file is a regular python file, and so you could write a function in it that would load your `"value"` from an external file, which in turn could be edited by the blog author as needed.